# How do I make a Spring aop comparison on expression?

Tags: xml, spring, javabeans, spring-aop

I need to get the value of the property name logLvl of bean id logConfig and make a comparison on expression.

```
<bean id="logConfig"
    class="com.celfocus.ufe.base.logging.domains.LoggingConfiguration">
    <property name="logDetails" value="STANDARD" />
    <property name="logLvl" value="COMPLET" />
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="ufeLogger">
        <aop:pointcut id="complete" expression="execution(* *.*(..)) and ($logConfig.logLvl=STANDARD)"  />
```

This piece of code gives an illegal identifier character `=`. What can I do to make this check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen anything making me think this would be possible--do you have documentation that demonstrates the use of expressions inside a pointcut like this? If anything, you could try using a SpEL escape `#{}`, but I'm skeptical. That'd be cool, though, if it worked.

My first approach would be to use the property value as a property on the aspect as well as the log config.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `==`? If you're doing a comparison, after all.